# LOAD QUERY from SQL

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Is there any way to run LOAD QUERY from a pure SQL viewer (dbeaver, squirrel, etc)?

I have only seen this is possible from CLP.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-load-query

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`MON_GET_UTILITY()`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-mon-get-utility-get-utilities-running-database) table function.